# Populate data in a postgres table using a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, postgresql, dataframe

I am working with python trying to connect with postgres, I created a table into my postgres database in the staging schema.

```
create table staging.data( Name varchar, Age bigint);
```

then I try to connect and insert my dataframe data into this table:

```
import psycopg2
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
  
conn_string = 'postgresql://myuser:password@host/database_name'

  
db = create_engine(conn_string)
conn = db.connect()
  
  
# our dataframe
data = {'Name': ['Tom', 'dick', 'harry'],
        'Age': [22, 21, 24]}
  
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_sql('staging.data', con=conn, if_exists='replace',
          index=False)
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string
                        )
conn.autocommit = True
cursor = conn.cursor()
  
sql1 = '''select * from staging.data;'''
cursor.execute(sql1)
for i in cursor.fetchall():
    print(i)
  
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

But the Python ends with no error message, and there is no data into my table from postgres.

Any idea about this?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are trying to use a schema other than `public`. Try passing in the schema name via the `schema` argument of `to_sql()` like this:

```
df.to_sql('data', con=conn, if_exists='replace', schema='staging', index=False)
```